# Incrementing filename in while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a script where i'm trying to capture a screenshot every second for 60 seconds and saving the files as date/time.jpg however it only creates a single file, how do I make the time update inside while loop?

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")

DISPLAY=:1 firefox http://www.bbc.co.uk > /dev/null 2>&1 &

SECONDS=0;
while sleep 1 && ((SECONDS <= 60)); do
DISPLAY=:1 import -window root $now.jpg

done
```

outputs

```
+ SECONDS=0
+ sleep 1
+ DISPLAY=:1
+ firefox http://www.bbc.co.uk
+ (( SECONDS <= 60 ))
+ DISPLAY=:1
+ import -window root -resize 1024x768 29092015-144315.jpg
+ sleep 1
+ (( SECONDS <= 60 ))
+ DISPLAY=:1
+ import -window root -resize 1024x768 29092015-144315.jpg
+ sleep 1
+ (( SECONDS <= 60 ))
+ DISPLAY=:1
+ import -window root -resize 1024x768 29092015-144315.jpg
+ sleep 1
```

Also instead of using time as the filename I don't mind using incrementing numbers i.e 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg

Comment: Try with moving second line into while block

Comment: The second line opens firefox to bbc.co.uk I only want to load it once and grab secreenshot every second.

Comment: I mean **now=$(date +"%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")** statement

Comment: ahh that's done it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value assigned for `now` variable is executed only once, when this line is evaluated and therefore you need to evaluate it every time you want to capture the picture.

Try this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

DISPLAY=:1 firefox http://www.bbc.co.uk > /dev/null 2>&1 &

SECONDS=0;
while sleep 1 && ((SECONDS <= 60)); do
now=$(date +"%d%m%Y-%H%M%S")
DISPLAY=:1 import -window root $now.jpg

done
```

And if you want to use save the files with increment numbers instead of the current date, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DISPLAY=:1 firefox http://www.bbc.co.uk > /dev/null 2>&1 &

SECONDS=0;
NUM_OF_FILE=0;
while sleep 1 && ((SECONDS <= 60)); do
NUM_OF_FILE=$((NUM_OF_FILE+1))
DISPLAY=:1 import -window root $NUM_OF_FILE.jpg

done
```

Comment: Thanks as per Kadir's answer this now works. I'd also like to use incremental numbered filenames instead how would I do that?